# Survery - Export to spreadsheet - shows all responses to contribute permission user

Tags: export, survey

I am quite new to SharePoint. I created a survey with below settings;
[image]

I have user who has contribute permission to this list. However when the user does 'Export to spreadsheet' from his account, he gets all responses. I believe this should not happen as he is not owner of the list.

Kindly let know what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing much,

This Survey thing is a 13 year old beast or maybe even goes back to SP2001

It has so many flaws, somet SharePoint users recreate functionality with a custom List and code